# Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0018

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I looked in the R.java file for the resource ID and the ID is a string. The string is the name of my app

```
<string name="AppName">Tip Calculator</string>
```

Please help. Thank you in advanced.

LogCat:

```
.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Tip Calculator from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0018
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Tip Calculator from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0018
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3030)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setLogo(ActionBarView.java:1031)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setDefaultLogo(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.Activity.initActionBar(Activity.java:1997)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2011)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at net.jamesbrookshire.tipcalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     ... 11 more
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Tip Calculator
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:408)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3021)
05-01 22:37:50.979: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     ... 20 more
```

I resolved my problem by starting a new project and adding my old code to the project a little each time and debugging each time. The cause of my problem was in my "MainActivity.java". I had some bad code that wasn't picked up by the debugger. Sorry this was and isn't very clear. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the string value? Please show some more code.

Comment: I have strings in 'res/values/strings.xml' this is string that is being referenced.        
`<resources>
    <string name="AppName">Tip Calculator</string>
</resources>`

Comment: Where you are using string in your code ?

Comment: It is used in the Manifest for "application android:label="@string/AppName"
android:logo="@string/AppName"> AND <activity android:label=@string/AppName">

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project ?

Comment: yes, and i have tried recreating the project. This app use to work but stopped working when Google updated to kitkat and updated their terms etc...

Comment: Have you update your ADT ?

Comment: yes, i did update. I also did a fresh install of eclipse and android sdk.

Comment: I am sorry can't help because of lack of details. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put strings in `res/value/string.xml`. Drawables are for images.

Comment: I have strings in 'res/values/strings.xml'        
`<resources>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="Bill">Bill Amount : $</string>
    <string name="TipPercent">Tip :%</string>
    <string name="default_Amount">0.00</string>
    <string name="default_Percent">15</string>
    <string name="Split">Split:</string>
    <string name="Total">Total Per Person : $0.00</string>
    <string name="GrandTotal">&quot;New Bill Amount : $0.00 &quot;</string>
    <string name="tipAmount">Tip Amount : $</string>
    <string name="AppName">Tip Calculator</string>
</resources>`

Comment: @user3595136 As i can see you have written special symbols in your string file which is not allowed to directly write. You need to write it in form of hexa values. So may it would be throwing errors. Just write the hexa values of special symbols.

Comment: You also need to define the encoding of your xml: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 0):

Your short and incomplete logs shows a `.MainActivity` in which you are referencing a drawable which doesn't exists. This error has nothing to do with your `AndroidManifest.xml`. And also this has nothing to do with your strings.xml file because the error states that a drawable named `Tip Calculator` is not found.

You may provide more lines from your logs which would give clarity to the error.